# CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and cookie file

Tags: curl, cookies, libcurl

I'm using CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR (curl libraries ), and I’m saving cookies in a file, "cookie.txt". I can't find it the file. Where is it? I searched in the project folder, nothing.

Here is my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,1);       // clean up session.
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,userAgentMozilla);        // set the user agent
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_URL,lien.toUtf8().constData());     // set the url 
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,data.size()+4);     // size of the request.
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,ba);  // aray of the POST request
res = curl_easy_perform(handle);
```

Comment: Do I have to put an absolute path ?

Answer (score 0):

of course you have to .

you can try this code :

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>__DIR__."/cookie.txt",
```

**OR**

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt",
```

Comment: There is no need for an absolute path. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an absolute path.
`CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` which is cleaning up the cookie session seems to conflict with `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. This will not clean up the cookie session, process the request and then save the new cookies to your file. Howewer, this will prevent the creation of a new cookie session in this request.
A correct code would be simply :

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,userAgentMozilla);        // set the user agent
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_URL,lien.toUtf8().constData());     // set the url 
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,data.size()+4);     // size of the request.
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,ba);  // aray of the POST request
res = curl_easy_perform(handle);
```